# find the plane which contains two points and the origin? vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

Consider the points $D = (1, −1, 5)$ and $E = (4, 3, −2)$
Find the plane $S_1$ which contains $D$, $E$ and the origin, in parametric form. 
Now find the equational form for $S_1$.

Comment: my question is how do i approach this...

Comment: i know that if we take the cross product of the first two vectors we get -13i+22j+7k which is normal to the plane. so let -13i+22j+7k = n. also DE=(3,4,-7). since it passes through the origin i beleive we can use n⋅(3,4,-7)=0 however i think the answer should be in the form ax+by+cz=0 so i think i have done something wrong in the working out. is anyone able to help me instead of downvoting for no reason ? :)

Comment: There is some useful explanation in the first answer to this question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/152467/parametric-form-of-a-plane

Comment: Great! You found the normal $(-13,22,7)$. So since the plane goes through the origin the equation is just $(x,y,z)\cdot(-13,22,7)=0$ or $-13x+22y+7z=0$. But you still want the parametric form.

Comment: oh !! thanks so much that makes much more sense now :)

Comment: is the parametric form 
{(x, y, z) ∈ R^3| (x, 13x-7z, z) | x,z ∈ R} ?

Comment: and  { (x, y, z) ∈ R^3 | -13x + 22y + 7z = 0 } would be the equational form ?

Comment: The parametric form expresses each of $x,y,z$ in terms of two parameters, say $s,t$. You know that the origin and $D$ are in the plane, so any point of the form $(s,-s,5s)$ must be in the plane. Similarly the origin and $E$ are in it, so any point of the form $(4t,3t,-2t)$ is in the plane. Hence also any point $(x,y,z)$ with $x=s+4t,y=-s+3t,z=5s-2t$. Yes, you have got the equational form.

Comment: oh ok i see so the parametric could be written as { (s+4t, −s+3t, 5s-2t) | s, t ∈ R } ?

Comment: Yes, that looks fine to me.

Comment: thank you, you have been very helpful :)